# Borel-Cantelli Application Question

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I have a question (at $\star$) regarding the solution to the question below:

> **Question.** Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that there exists a sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\frac{X_n}{a_n} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$.

**Solution.** For some $b$, note that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > b) \to 0$ as $b \to \infty$. So, choose some $b_n > 0$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > b_n) < \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Then we can choose $a_n$ as follows:

$$a_n = \max\{n, \max_{k=1, \dots, n} b_k\}.$$

Therefore, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \epsilon a_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > a_n) < \infty, \tag{$\star$}$$

and the result follows by Borel-Cantelli.

---

For $(\star)$, I don't quite see how this holds for all $\epsilon$. Suppose we had a sequence of  Gaussians with mean $0$, i.e. let $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2)$, and so $|X_n|$ are half-Gaussians. If $\epsilon \geq 1$, then surely $(\star)$ holds, but if $\epsilon < 1$ I don't see how it holds for any sequence of $a_n$.

Where is my flaw in thinking?

---

**Edit:** From @Michael's comments, a more elegant (and correct) approach is for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $\epsilon_n := \frac{a_n}{n}$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \epsilon_n) < \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \epsilon_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} < \infty.$$

Therefore, by B.C. the result follows.

Comment: I would eliminate the phrase "For some $b$" from the starting sentence of your proof.  The equation ($\star$) is incorrect if $0<\epsilon<1$.  I would personally change the proof to just define $a_n$ as a value such that $P[|X_n|> (1/n)a_n] \leq 1/2^n$.

Comment: You could replace the phrase "For some $b$..."  in your opening sentence with "For each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$..."

Comment: I see. That's much nicer.

Comment: I do not follow the argument in your edit: How do you get $P[|X_n|>\epsilon b_n] \leq \epsilon/2^n$? You do not need to use any $\epsilon$ variable in the proof.

Comment: My mistake in haste of editing.